# using windows gadget "connectionChanged" event in my c# program

Tags: c#, winforms, wireless, wifi, windows-desktop-gadgets

I'm writing simple program which using some wlan info. For example I need to know when my wlan interface change his network. While searching network I've found this [msdn reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa965856%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) which I believe would solve my problem. And my question is: is it possible to use it in my c#, winforms application?

Answer (score 1):

there is another stack overflow post that may help you out.

Will this work out for you

[Managing wireless network connection in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/285665/managing-wireless-network-connection-in-c/285696#285696)

Comment: I'm using that library but i did notice that event... meh. Thanks, that solves my problem :) Although it's not answer to my question so only "arrow up" ;)