# Using C# or Powershell to scan all available wireless networks and connect to a specific SSID

Tags: c#, powershell, wlanapi

I am trying to write a script that scans all the available wireless networks and connects to a specific network (SSID). Does anyone have a sample code written already for this? I cannot install a third party software (managed wifi api) due to some restrictions.

Answer (score 1):

Check this related article:
[Managing wireless network connection in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/285665/managing-wireless-network-connection-in-c)
. There are some answers, as well as a link to a sample app on codeproject that connects and shows basic wireless info (signal strength, etc) using a UI.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `netsh`:

```
netsh wlan connect ssid=YOURSSID name=PROFILENAME
```

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToConnectToAWirelessWIFINetworkFromTheCommandLineInWindows7.aspx

Answer (score 0):

- [**wlanscan**](http://poshcode.org/1731)  by Kris Cieslak

Comment: Thanks Kris. This script only shows all the available SSIDs. How do I connect to a specific SSID?