# Display, Connect and Disconnect Wireless Networks

Tags: c#, wireless

I hope someone can give me your help ...
(Any sample code would be appreciated)

What I intend to do is display in a ListBox the Wireless Network detects my computer.

(connect and disconnect the selected network)

I intend to do it in C# 2010

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- [Managed Wifi API on CodePlex](http://managedwifi.codeplex.com/)
- [Managed Wifi API code example](http://managedwifi.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/41381#213980)
- [SO post: Managing wireless network connection in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/285665/managing-wireless-network-connection-in-c-sharp)